# how to fadeIn the div element which has a display property value 'none' in CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.quality-link').click(function () {

    $('#aboutus').fadeOut('slow', function () {

        $('#quality').css("display","block").hide().fadeIn('slow');

        });
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: you can check whether div has display property none `$('#quality').css('display') == 'none'`

Comment: You've got too many `});`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work fine.

Just check your code for syntax errors.

```js
$('.quality-link').click(function() {

  $('#aboutus').fadeOut('slow', function() {
    $('#quality').fadeIn('slow');
  });

});

$('#bring_back_about').click(function() {
  $('#quality').fadeOut('slow', function() {
    $('#aboutus').fadeIn('slow');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="quality-link">click me</button>

<button id="bring_back_about">bring back about</button>


<div id="quality" style="display: none;">
  Quality div
</div>
<div id="aboutus">
  About us
</div>
```

Comment: how can i get back the fadeOut div element onclick another button??

Comment: Do you want to hide the quality div again after getting back the fadeOut div ?

Comment: Please check updated answer and let me know if it works for you :)

Comment: yes,i want to fadeOut the quality div and fadeIn previous fadeOut div